# curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations error coming when using p12 certificate file as CA certificate

Tags: openssl, libcurl, pkcs#12

I am running the below command in debian linux but I get the error

```
curl --cert  /home/debian/cert/new.p12:Password1 --cacert /home/debian/cert/cacert.p12  --capath /home/debian/cert/ --cert-type P12  https://192.168.10.2:443/example

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /home/debian/cert/cacert.p12
  CApath: /home/debian/cert/
```

Please let me know curl will support CA certificate type P12. Because I have used PEM type file, it is working fine.

Comment: what version of curl are you using?

Comment: I am using curl 7.26.0   *** curl 7.26.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).